# Two dimensional random variables Probability problem

Tags: probability

i'm trying to this question (Answer is provided)
[image: Q&A]

I've solved a) and b) well, but have difficulties in c).

I've tried to isolate: $X^2 + Y^2 \leq 9 => X \leq \sqrt{9-Y^2} $
Then, I have $P(X \leq x)$, so i'm trying to set x = $\sqrt{9-Y^2}$

if $\sqrt{9-Y^2} \geq 1$ then P = 1, else, P = 0.5. But this direction doesn't gets me to the answer (3\4).

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking too much and too complicated. The is no need for algebraic manipulations at all. $X^2+Y^2\leq 9$ means either $X=1$ (with probability $1/2$) or $X=0, Y\leq 3$ (which has probability $1/4$).

Comment: Great it's much simpler then I though, (I will accept in 7 minutes when i'm able)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you have the joint distribution $(X,Y)$. Then, $$\mathbb{P}(X^2+Y^2\leq9)=\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in B)$$

where $B=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 9\}$.

But, $\mathcal{R}_{XY}=\{0,1\}\times\{0,...,6\}$ and then $$\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in B)=\mathbb{P}((X,Y)=(0,0))+\mathbb{P}((X,Y)=(0,1))+\mathbb{P}((X,Y)=(0,2))+\mathbb{P}((X,Y)=(0,3))+\mathbb{P}((X,Y)=(1,0))+\mathbb{P}((X,Y)=(1,1))+\mathbb{P}((X,Y)=(1,2))$$